# Android Studio error:<identifier> expected

Tags: android, android-studio

This SensorTestActivity.java in which Android Studio marks R in red:

```
package szabojanos.accelerometer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SensorTestActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private boolean color = false;
private View view;
private long lastUpdate;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    view = findViewById(R.id.textview);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        getAccelerometer(event);
    }

}

private void getAccelerometer(SensorEvent event) {
    float[] values = event.values;
    float x = values[0];
    float y = values[1];
    float z = values[2];

    float accelationSquareRoot = (x * x + y * y + z * z)
            / (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
    long actualTime = event.timestamp;
    if (accelationSquareRoot >= 2) //
    {
        if (actualTime - lastUpdate < 200) {
            return;
        }
        lastUpdate = actualTime;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Az eszköz fel volt rázva", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        if (color) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        color = !color;
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

And this is android_sensor_test.xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I was following this Tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSensor/article.html#tutorial-accelerometer
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clean-Rebuild** Your project at first  and then  **Import R**

Basic Syntax

```
import szabojanos.accelerometer.R;
```

**FYI**

Call **`requestWindowFeature`** after **`super.onCreate`**.

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);// Call this after super.onCreate
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `.R` import. You could auto fix this by going on the red line and press the combination `ALT+ENTER` and choose `import yourpackage.R`

Answer (score 0):

import yourpackage.R and if there is any issues in youe xml file please resolve then try to clean and build.